# Replacing a string in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, replace

I'm trying to replace a string with another string in Haskell. Here's the code that I have so far, but it doesn't exactly work.

```
replace :: [Char] -> [Char]
replace [] = []
replace (h:t) =
    if h == "W"
    then "VV" : replace t
    else h : replace t
```

I want to be able to accomplish this for example: if the string is "HELLO WORLD", the result should be "HELLO VVORLD". I think words/unwords would be helpful, but not exactly sure how to implement it.

Comment: In addition to what [J.Abrahamson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/476408/j-abrahamson) gave in [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21422305/205936), read the types in your functions carefully. You use `[Char]`, which means that it can only take `Char`s and nothing else. Note the types of `(:)` too. Yeah, Haskell's a lot of fun! :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's worth being explicit about what `String` actually is. For instance, you're looking for the test case:

```
replace ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', 'W', 'O', 'R', 'L', 'D']
==
['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', 'V', 'V', 'O', 'R', 'L', 'D']
```

Now, when you pattern match on a list like this the head of the list will be the first *character* of the string

```
> case "Hello world" of (c:rest) -> print c
'H'
```

So we can't match it with a string literal like `"W"`. In a similar way, we can't use cons (`(:)`) to prepend a string to another string, we can only add a single character!

```
> 'P' : "hello"
"Phello"
```

Instead, we'll use `(++) :: String -> String -> String` to append two strings.

```
replace :: [Char] -> [Char]
replace [] = []
replace (h:t) =
    if h == 'W'
      then "VV" ++ replace t
      else h : replace t
```

Which ought to work as expected

```
> replace "Hello World"
"Hello VVorld"
```

Comment: What is the runtime of `++`? Isn't it beneficial to cons both characters instead, `'V' : 'V' : replace t` ?

Comment: `(++)` is linear in the size of its left argument, so it's just about the same thing here. It's likely GHC would even inline `(++)` away entirely given it's applied to a constant.

Comment: Nope, it depends crucially on the idea of expanding characters only. You need some kind of sliding window to achieve word replacements.

Answer (score 4):

With pattern matching:

```
replace ('W':xs) = "VV" ++ replace xs
replace (x:xs) = x : replace xs
replace [] = []
```

With for comprehension:

```
replace xs = concat [if x == 'W' then "VV" else [x] | x <- xs]
```

With monads:

```
replace = (>>= (\ x -> if x == 'W' then "VV" else [x]))
```

With a fold:

```
replace = foldr (\ x -> if x == 'W' then ("VV"++) else (x:)) []
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `"VV" :: [Char]` but not `Char`.

And `"W"` is `[Char]`, but not `Char`

```
replace :: [Char] -> [Char]
replace [] = []
replace (h:t) =
    if h == 'W'
    then 'V' : 'V' : replace t
    else h : replace t
```

Comment: Thanks, one more quick question, how can I modify this to replace words. For example, if the input string is: "I am from United States", and I want to replace "United States" with "Australia" so the result should be "I am from Australia".

Comment: @user3247171 Then you should use Landei answer